# Issue in SQL Server TRUNCATE statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a daily running job on SQL Server. I used truncate table and as per the stored procedure gives result I fill data in that table. But recently I have added one column in table and stored procedure. Stored procedure showing values in that column but it is not coming in table.

What should be the issue.

I am very thankful if I got solution.

Comment: please give additionnal info about your table and your stored proc.

Comment: What does "Store procedure showing values in that column but it is not coming in table" mean?

Comment: If I execute Store procedure then the column is having value but in daily job that values should be reflect in Table as it was previous but when I added new column it is showing NULL only.

Comment: One thing you can be pretty sure of is that the contents of the table have nothing to do with a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement, as that removes all the data. As for what else could be wrong, you'll have to show the table definition, the stored procedure and how you're executing it. We can't debug remotely.

Comment: I am using like

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[ABC]

  insert into [dbo].[ABC]
  exec [dbo].[XYZ]

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your question and post your full code, plus table definition. Posting a single line in a comment isn't very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Actually there was not an issue with truncate statement.

My stored procedure columns and table columns getting mismatched.
When I saw the result and counted the columns in table and stored procedure I get idea. Then I removed some unwanted columns from stored procedure and matched columns with table columns, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try by putting all the columns in the `INSERT INTO` statement like below:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[ABC] 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ABC](COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3,...) --Add all the columns here
EXEC [dbo].[XYZ]
```